# Is there a function that can jump over outside of a function?

Tags: c++

Is there a function like example: goto that can jump over functions? Lets say I have this code :

```
#include <iostream>

void function1() {
    //dothis1
    //dothis2
    //jump to other function
}

int main() {
    std::cout<<"a";
    //go to here (jump)
    std::cout<<"b";
}
```

Comment: Just call the another function to which you want to jump to?

Comment: You can 'call' another function from within a function. Look up what this means.

Comment: Call `function1` in `main`, when it returns it will jump back to `main`.

Comment: @AnoopRana nonono, i mean like the function have several code on it and i just want it to jump over the specific code, not the entire function

Comment: Just for a start, what control-flow elements of C++ are you aware of? Like `if`, `else`, `return` and function calls?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt if

Comment: Wouldn't you just add another parameter to the function and use that to decide where to really start execution(jump/goto to)? Not that it really makes any sense to do so. What are you trying to achieve? (We know how you're trying to do it - not helping.) What problem do you see this scheme as solving?

Comment: If that's all, keep studying your C++ tutorial. Sorry, but SO can't (and doesn't want to) teach the basics of a language. BTW: Type "[c++] essential resources" into the search bar above.

Comment: Divide the function you want to jump into into several separate functions. Then you can just call the one specifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just call the another function to which you want to jump to as shown below. In the below program we call `function1` from inside `main` and when `function1` finishes the control will be automatically returned to the calling function `main`.

Then from inside `function1` we call `dothis1` and `dothis2` and when `dothis1` and `dothis2` finishes control will be automatically returned to the calling function `function1`.

```
void dothis1()
{
    std::cout<<"entered dothis1"<<std::endl;
}
void dothis2()
{
    std::cout<<"entered dothis2"<<std::endl;
}
void function1()
{
    std::cout<<"entered function1"<<std::endl;
   //call dothis1 
   dothis1(); 
   
   //now call dothis2
   dothis2();
}


int main()
{
    //call function1 
    function1();
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the above program can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/Ni9Hy6lgt):

```
entered function1
entered dothis1
entered dothis2
```

Comment: wait, gonna test it!

Comment: @AbhiDevs Sure, i have also given a [demo link](https://www.onlinegdb.com/Ni9Hy6lgt) where you can directly try out the code.

Comment: can u do it in another function outside main()?

Comment: @AbhiDevs In the example, `dothis1` and `dothis2` are separate functions that are different from `main`. I thought this is what you wanted when you said "another function outside main". If not, can you clarify what you mean by "another function outside main". Also you might want to refer to a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: hmm can i do it like :
in function 1 it will call function 2 and in function 2 it will call function 1. I got an error when compiling with that style.

Comment: @AbhiDevs Yes, you can call the functions recursively. See [demo](https://onlinegdb.com/G0WChCSvz). But note you have make sure that the recursion ends for a given condition otherwise the two functions will keep on calling each other and the program will keep on printing "entered function1" , "entered function2" as shown in [this demo](https://onlinegdb.com/G0WChCSvz).

Comment: I get a compiler error :/

Comment: @AbhiDevs To make sure that you don't have a typo in your code, just copy/paste the code that i have given at [here](https://onlinegdb.com/G0WChCSvz). I have tested the program and it compiles fine. You must be getting some other error. Can you share the error description here.

Comment: nonono, i read the error and the error is like this : function1 was not declared in this scope (this in on void function2())

Comment: may i show you my code? do you have a discord or smthing?

Comment: @AbhiDevs You can just paste you code [here](https://onlinegdb.com/CKiU8BDdi) and then click on share and a link will be presented to you and then you can share that link with me here.

Comment: [link](https://onlinegdb.com/q21ARPEnh) here

Comment: @AbhiDevs As i suspected, you did not exactly copy/pasted the code that i gave in the link. In particular, the problem is that you were missing the 2 function declarations that i provided at the very starting of my code. Look closely at line `8` and `9` in [this demo](https://onlinegdb.com/yGohTtZNR) link. I have added some comment there so that you can spot it easily.

Comment: wait a second...